# Could not create the view: Drag Placerholder; java.lang.Exception at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an error when starting Eclipse which is :

> Could not create the view: Drag Placerholder.

No programs were starting. Need your help.

I put some of the stacktrace here :

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart(ViewReference.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:316)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at...
```

Comment: I toke a look in log file and find one of this error :

`org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.tests.TestException: Test of exception handling`

Comment: And this was the first error when starting session eclipse : `FrameworkEvent ERROR`;
`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.completions [1046]
  Another singleton bundle selected: osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.9.0.201707061630-RELEASE"; osgi.identity="org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.completions"; singleton:="true"

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1620)
 at ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. Just go here to lear more about migrating from STS Gradle to Buildshipthis is the valuable link : [Migration guide from STS Gradle to Buildship](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/wiki/Migration-guide-from-STS-Gradle-to-Buildship).

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thank you for ansewring. I'll try that and tell you.

Comment: Amazing, Thank you so much @YagamiLight. It works for me.